# Calling a service with python on bluemix

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, text-to-speech, ibm-watson

I'm using python on the IBM Bluemix platform. How can I do a call to the text-to-speech Watson service? I have the string inside my python code and I need to pass this text to be read.

Comment: See https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/text-to-speech-python for starter sample application

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you already have a Bluemix account and added text to speech Watson API to your Bluemix workspace, you have the credentials to access the API (restful).

If you were requesting using the CURL linux app, it would be something like this

```
curl -u "xxxxx729-b03f-4403-8adf-c5418ee4ea05":"xxxxxiWtmVoG" "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize?text=Hello+World" -H "accept: audio/flac" > sound.flac
```

Using Python, it can be

```
import requests

headers = {'accept': 'audio/flac'}

r = requests.get('https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize?text=Hello+World', auth=('xxxxx729-b03f-4403-8adf-c5418ee4ea05', 'xxxxxiWtmVoG'), headers=headers)

with open('/home/leo/sound.flac', 'wb') as fd:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(1024):
        fd.write(chunk)
```

See http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/ for details on the requests package.

See https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/text-to-speech/api/v1/ for text2Speech documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much @Leo... everything you explained here was very useful... it was what I needed to start...

Comment: Then how about upvoting the answer or tagging it as the correct answer? Just a thought. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Best thing is to use [Watson Developer Cloud Python SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk)